# General form of the coefficients of $1/(f(1/z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Let $f(z) = z + \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} a_n z^n$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disk.
I'd like to compute the coefficients of $1/(f(1/z))$ which is a Laurent series. Of course, using the algorithm for division, I get the beginning $$1/(f(1/z)) = z - a_2 + (a_2^2-a_3) \frac{1}{z} + \dots $$ but I would like to know if I can get a closed formula for all the coefficients $b_n$ of $1/(f(1/z))$ in terms of the coefficients $a_n$ of $f$. Thanks for any help.

Comment: See Pommerenke's book, univalent functions, page 70 under the Grunsky coefficients topic.

Comment: It's not freely available on the net. Could you please paste the answer and I would gladly upvote and accept it. :)

Comment: Actually I managed to go to the library to see the book and the formula that he gives is only partial (not further than $z^{-5}$).

Comment: As far as I know there is not a closed form for $b_n$'s, otherwise most of coefficients bound would be found for Bieberbach conjecture in past century. Also try https://mathoverflow.net.

Comment: Interesting, so you mean that a closed formula would automatically imply certain theorems linked to bieberbach conjecture ? (Clearly the coeff 1/z implies the base case of Zalcman conjecture but I don't know anything else).

Comment: The Zalcman conjecture and a generalized form (obtained by Ma) holds for close-to-convex and starlike functions as well. See Ma paper "Generalized Zalcman Conjecture for Starlike and Typically Real Functions" 1999.